# How to flatten an array before applying arrayOf('schema') in normalizrJS

Tags: javascript, normalizr

Suppose a user has favorited many cats and the api endpoint gives a list of cats when asked for user's favorites:

```
const catsList = [{id:1,name:"catA"},{id:2,name:"catB"},{id:3,name:"catC"}];

// ex: GET http://app.com/api/favorites =>  results in following json
{favorites:[{id:2,name:"catB"},{id:3,name:"catC"}]} 
// the result is the list of cats 

//and normalizr schema 
const cats = new Schema('cats');
const favorites = new Schema('favorites');
```

now my question is, how will I normalize these entities so that I have the following result,

```
  entities.favorites=[2,3]; //2 and 3 are cats
  entities.cats=[{id:1,name:"a"},{id:2,name:"b"},{id:3,name:"c"}];
```

how will I accomplish this with normalizr ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const cats = new Schema('cats');

const response = {
  favorites: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "catB"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "catC"
  }]
}

const normalized = normalize(response, {
  favorites: arrayOf(cats)
})
```

The `normalized` value will be like

```
{
  result: {
    favorites: [2, 3]
  },
  entities: {
    cats: {
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: "catB"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "catC"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It’s actually pretty important that `normalized.entities` is an object rather than an array—otherwise it would be slow to query by ID.

At this point you are free to transform this representation anyhow you like.